Can costs allowed to be written off for tax purposes also be written off for maaser?
As a freelancer, it is very tempting to use tax returns as a way to track the total maaserable income.
The only thing is that people tend to write off all kinds of stuff that "could be used for business" whether it is really used or not.
Separating all of these out would be quite cumbersome for anyone who has hundreds of invoices per year spent on things that are used for business, personal, or mixed reasons. Weeding out items blatantly dedicated to personal use is hard enough, figuring out controversial items makes all this even more painful.
Printer ink (and paper) - is one expected to really keep track of how much is used for personal vs business documents?
GPT, newspaper, all kinds of software subscriptions? Desk, chairs, headphones, all stationary, petrol, parking, car insurance, electricity, water, SIM card, internet, Yacht / Golf clubs (people look for business connections there), bicycles? Is it enough that you use something for business once to justify its purchase? Is it enough to have an intention to maybe use it at some point?
Is there space for a kula that says - if that's good enough for the government (as far as reducing taxable base is concerned) it's good enough for maaser?

Who said it's good enough for the government?

Every accountant I've ever had. If you make a film about how you've never used anything you'd bought for work they might come for you. But if you use your purchases just once symbolically, you're off the hook and they don't get to question the rationality of your business decisions (unless it's outright fraud). And that's why accounts refuse to write certain things off, sometimes the government releases regulation notes where they poskim certain cases that were otherwise ambiguous.

For example, in Israel as a freelancer, working from home (not necessarily exclusively) you get to write 25% off utilities - they had to pick a number as it can't really even be determined neither by the government nor by the freelancers themselves.

if you your tax return as your income, how do you deal with other credits or deductions that wouldn't count as expenses against your business. i.e. child credit, medical expenses etc.

Why not just take maaser from your after-tax income?

@Yoreinu none of this applies in Israel but business costs do. Avrohom Yitzhok that’s exactly what I would like to do - the after tax income is what remains after deducted expenses and taxes. Just I have a hashash that not every expense accepted by the state is also accepted by maaser

@Yoreinu I was told by my rov that childcare expenses can be deducted from income before calculating maaser, because it's a necessary cost in order for me to be able to work. The same for transportation to and from work.

@AvrohomYitzchok that becomes complicated when you have benefits being taken out of your paycheck pre-tax, some of which are non-maaserable, and others of which are. For example, health insurance is pre-tax but I still have to give maaser on the money I spent on insurance.

@rudolfovic I also run my business from home in Israel and do not deduct the 25% because I would incur these costs (arnona, electricity, water) anyway. See my detailed answer for the rationale (and please don't shoot the messenger :->)

@Esther i like you Rov, definitely a "chap" i never thought or heard of, yet very straightforward. will have to go ask mine about that

The consensus of sources I saw on the topic is that you can only deduct true business expenses from the "maaser base", i.e., expenses which are truly necessary to the running of your business. Expenses you would have incurred if you didn't have your business should not be deducted. The following examples should help make this come alive

Food: money spent on food during a business trip can be deducted, however only the difference between what the food would cost him at home and what it costs on the trip. Pne may not buy more expensive food which one doesn't eat at home and deduct it from maaser

Clothing: one can deduct the cost of a business suit but only if one would not have purchased the suit otherwise

Business trip combined with pleasure: one can only deduct the cost of the trip if one would not have taken the trip otherwise, and any expenses for the personal time cannot be deducted

Car used for business and personal: a car purchased for both business and personal use is not considered a business expense if he would have purchased the car even if he didn't need it for business. A calculation must be made to determine of amount of gas, repairs, etc. which is spent for business use, and only that portion can be deducted.


As you note, this can be quite complicated to track. R Feuer explicitly writes "This calculation can become very detailed ... one should be scrupulous to deduct only the added expense which actually results from engaging in business".
Sources: R Shimon Taub's The laws of tzedaka and maaser (pp. 137ff), R Yisrael Bronstein's The halachos of maaser kesafim (pp. 147ff), R Avrohom Chaim Feur's the tzedaka treasury (pp. 133ff)
Of course, consult your rabbi
before implementing anything you learn here.
